# Layout in service will not adjust with keyboard

Tags: android

I have a floating layout in a service that has an `EditText`, when I click on the `EditText` I have the keyboard appearing but the layout is not adjusting.  I have been digging for 2 days and none of the answers work for me.  I have set windowSoftInputMode in the manifest and set `setFitsSystemWindows` to true on my layout as well.

FloatingService.java

```
 public class FloatingService extends Service implements View.OnClickListener {
private WindowManager windowManager;
private LinearLayout contentLayout;

private View mainView;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams mainParams = getMainParams();
    contentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    contentLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(true);

    windowManager.addView(contentLayout, mainParams);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mainView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_floating_iv, contentLayout);

    EditText editText = (EditText) mainView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }
    });
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (contentLayout != null) {
        windowManager.removeView(contentLayout);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

private WindowManager.LayoutParams getMainParams() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mainParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    mainParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM ;
    mainParams.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE;

    return mainParams;
}
```

Manifest

```
<service
        android:name="com.jibmobile.pogotoolkit.services.FloatingService"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: Why you are uysing service, You can use activity on place of service

Comment: It has to float above all apps, like facebook chathead.  You cannot do that, to the best of my knowledge, with just an activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out to be the FLAG that I was using.  The below code fixed my issues.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams mainParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```